# Generating Fuchsian Groups

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Suppose $\Lambda$ is a finite (more than $2$ points) or countable discrete set in the unit disk $\mathbb{D}\subset\mathbb{C}$, how does one generate the Fuchsian group $\Gamma$ for which $\mathbb{D}/\Gamma\cong \mathbb{D}\backslash\Lambda$.

For finite sets, for example, is it simply a free product of cyclic groups generated by parabolic elements?

Comment: Does $\cong$ sign mean "conformal"? Then you need the full power of the uniformization theorem to prove this.

Comment: I know the mapping exists, that's not the problem. I'm really trying to get to grips with the links between the set $\Lambda$ and the group $\Gamma$.

Comment: Your guess about parabolic elements in the finite case is correct. If course, this does not determine the group.

Comment: Thanks - that's all I need to know really. This is not a familiar area for me so I'm not always sure I can trust my intuition.